# what's the difference between seq-to-seq and many-to-many?

Tags: time-series, forecasting, recurrent-neural-network, seq2seq

I'm trying to build a model to forecast multi-steps ahead time series data like stock market data.

And I found out that many precedents projects are done with many-to-many RNNs, not seq-to-seq.

Is there any reason for that?
And what's the difference between those two algorithms?

Answer (score 4):

As far as I can tell, the difference is more in the input/outputs than the structure of the network.

In a **seq2seq** model, you give the desired output, as a part of the input. And the output is the same as that part of the input, but shifted by one time step. The following chart is taken from [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/seq2seq).

[image]

In contrast to the above architecture, a **many to many** model, does not include the output as a part of the input. As show [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/2654):

[image]